# HTML5 enabled browser for Windows Mobile 6

Tags: windows-mobile, html, local-storage, mobile-webkit

I did some research on Google but I couldn't find any HTML5 browser for Windows Mobile 6. The main resource I'm looking for in HTML5 is WebDatabase and/or localStorage.

With a little research I found Iris (http://www.freewarepocketpc.net/ppc-download-iris-browser.html), a Webkit based browser with some HTML5 features, but localStorage and Web Database doesn't work on it.

Does anyone know any browser with storage capability for Windows Mobile 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ZetaKey](http://www.zetakey.com/) is attempting exactly this. They claim to support application caching and local storage in their WinMo browser.

Comment: Finally a decent competitor. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

dorothy browser is webkit based. http://www.dorothybrowser.com/ but i dont think they've got html 5 support in yet, might be worth keeping an eye on tho.

Comment: they have a little HTML5 support (scored 48/160 in html5test.com), it's still in beta and not so stable.

Comment: Dorothy keeps crashing when opening GMail

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mini kind of supports HTML5. You should check that out.

Comment: Yes, Opera Mini has some HTML5 features, but storage functions are not avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

Tau Technologies(the maintainer of RhoMobile platform) introduces a WebKit-based browser engine for WinCE/WM

- Full HTML5 compliance
- High performance
- Compatible with WinCE 5/6, Compact 7 and Windows Mobile
- Utilizes Cairo Graphics with FreeType support for superb rendering
- Can be built in third-party products on the licensing basis

Regards,
Konstantin Rybas

Answer (score -1):

FYI, Intermec launched the HTML5 browser to their full range of product. They also have some teaching YouTube videos.

Going Offline with the Intermec HTML5 Browser Part 1 - YouTube

www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeaaazxeYzM

25 Sep 2012 - 3 min - Uploaded by intermec
Unique to the industry, Intermec's HTML5 offering includes a true webbrowser application ...

Comment: the intermec html5 browser is a ZetaKey browser. The intermec one will ONLY run on Intermec devices running WM6.1 or WEH6.5

Comment: Based on your other posts and profile, you appear to recommending a product you're affiliated with. If you do, you must disclose that it's yours. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. Please see: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for $SITENAME$?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).